# how to make scroll bar overlay content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How do I get the scrollbar to overlay div content?

already tried to use `track` with transparent background, but it does not work

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent}
```

remains the same, occupying part of the content

[image]

```css
.faq-body {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #7b7d7f;
}

.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}
.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #7b7d7f;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10rem;
}
.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  position: absolute;
  right: -3rem;
  top: -50rem;
  background: transparent;
}

.faq-question {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 1.3;
  color: #15191b;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-body">
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you need a custom or default scrollbar?

Comment: @VitorAvanço custom scroll bar within a div, overriding content, 
as in the picture as in my question.

Sou brasileiro também ;)

Comment: I tried to reach this with an iframe, but had no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to get a similar result:

**Javascript Lib**

Use http://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

https://jsfiddle.net/w0a5Ls6h/

Pro:

- Browser compatibility
- Satisfactory result

Cons:

- 3rd javascript

or

**Only CSS**

```
<style>
  .faq-body {
      width: 250px;
      height: 400px;
      background: #fff;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      border: 1px solid #7b7d7f;
    }

    .faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 7px;
    }
    .faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      border-radius: 10rem;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
    }


    .faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
      background: transparent;
    }

    .faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
      background: transparent;
    }
    .faq-question {
      padding: 20px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
      line-height: 1.3;
      color: #15191b;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
</style>
```

Cons:

- Browser compatibility
- Similar result but not satisfactory

Comment: CSS solution doesn't work, lib javascript worked perfectly.

Comment: Unable to get the CSS version to work.This is trickier than it looks.

Answer (score 6):

`overflow: overlay` works in some browsers (Chrome, Edge) but not Firefox. Supposedly `scrollbar-gutter` is suppose to help, but it doesn't look like any browsers have implemented this yet.

Here's a reference to browser support:
https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay

```css
.faq-body {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  border: 1px solid #7b7d7f;
}

.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}
.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #7b7d7f;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10rem;
}
.faq-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  position: absolute;
  right: -3rem;
  top: -50rem;
  background: transparent;
}

.faq-question {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 1.3;
  color: #15191b;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-body">
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      Question
    </div>
  </div>
```