# Can i use scrollbar-gutter to force overlay scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

According to *caniuse* the [`overflow: overlay`](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay) property is deprecated and

> related functionality being standardized as [the `scrollbar-gutter` property](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter).

A similiar reference is made over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68472834/4593433), too.

The `scrollbar-gutter` property is already supported in most modern browsers, but I do not understand how, or if I am able to use this to force (or at least nudge the browser to use) **overlay scrollbars**?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: I too wasn't able to find a solution. Stuck with `overlay`