How to make a scrollbar that floats above content with only CSS
I want to make a scrollbar that floats above the overflowing content, without taking up space, like this:

I've tried using position: absolute but it had no effect.
Also overflow: overlay is removed from all browsers.
And scrollbar-gutter: stable doesn't seem to be the way since it takes up space.
Example container:


div.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {    
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #00000055;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
</div>




Where’s the HTML and rest of the css? position won’t change anything about the scroll bar

I've added an example.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862671/how-to-make-scroll-bar-overlay-content
refer here

overlay having been removed, I don't believe this can be done using pure CSS, you'll need to implement your own using e.g. JS.



div.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {    
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #00000055;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
</div>



In one of your file, there is probably a code like:
::-webkit-scrollbar {    
    background-color: transparent;
}

Just try commenting background-color: transparent; this line and check, it will set the scrollbar to default.

The question is asking how to have the scrollbar float above the content, not how to make it visible where it is normally.

background-color on webkit-scrollbar actually enforces scrollbar to take its own space (with transparent or some other background color). So after unapplying, scrollbar will float over content

I don't think so, but if I am wrong perhaps you could provide a runnable snippet which demonstrates unapplying color to make the scrollbar float above content..

Sure, ive edited pls check

The scrollbar does not float above the content but sits to the side of it (on a desktop/laptop - of course it is totally different on e.g. Safari on IOS).
